# All of nodes in linkedlist are the same, seems insertion is not working

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have a linked list in C++, after inserting several nodes now I see that all of them are the same, although I'm using different values to add to node each time, but it's like all of them are the same, even when trying to change a node all of them are changing together or it's the same node that is always being returned, I don't know.

```
class node
{
    public:
        int ochance = 3;

        string question;

        string option1;
        int peopleeffectop1;
        int courteffectop1;
        int treasuryeffectop1;

        string option2;
        int peopleeffectop2;
        int courteffectop2;
        int treasuryeffectop2;

        node *next; 
};

class list
{
    private:
        node *head, *tail;

    public:
        list()
        {
            head=NULL;
            tail=NULL;
        }

        void createnode(int value , string q , string ans1 , int ans1ef1 , int ans1ef2, int ans1ef3 , string ans2, int ans2ef1 , int ans2ef2, int ans2ef3  )
        {
            node *temp = new node;

            temp->ochance = value;
            temp->question = q;
            temp->option1 = ans1;
            temp->peopleeffectop1 = ans1ef1;
            temp->courteffectop1  = ans1ef2;
            temp->treasuryeffectop1 = ans1ef3;
            temp->option2 = ans2;
            temp->peopleeffectop2 = ans2ef1;
            temp->courteffectop2  = ans2ef2;
            temp->treasuryeffectop2 = ans2ef3;
            temp->next = NULL;

            if(head == NULL)
            {
                head = temp;
                tail = temp;
                temp = NULL;
            }
            else
            {   
                tail->next = temp;
                tail = temp;
            }
        }

        node getnth(int pos)
        {
            node* tmp = new node;
            tmp = head;
            int i = 0; 

            while(tmp!=NULL)
            {
                if (i=pos)
                {
                    return *tmp;
                }
                i++;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }

        int getlen()
        {
            node* tmp = new node;
            tmp = head;
            int i = 0; 

            while(tmp!=NULL)
            {
                i++;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }

            return i;
        }

        void minus(int pos)
        {
            node* tmp = new node;
            tmp = head;
            int i = 0; 

            while(tmp!=NULL)
            {
                if (i=pos)
                {
                    tmp->ochance -=1;
                }
                i++;
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }

        void delete_first()
        {
            node *temp = new node;
            temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete temp;
        }

        void delete_last()
        {
            node *current = new node;
            node *previous = new node;
            current = head;
            while(current->next != NULL)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;    
            }
            tail = previous;
            previous->next = NULL;
            delete current;
        }

        void delete_position(int pos)
        {
            node *current = new node;
            node *previous = new node;
            current = head;
            for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
            previous->next = current->next;
        }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `if (i = pos)` is probably a bug. It's assigning rather than comparing.

Comment: Why are you building your own linked list when the standard library has both `std::list` and `std::forward_list` already? Also; why are you using a linked list in the first place? Unless you really need it's property of not moving elements in memory on insertion/deletion, it's one of the *worst performing* data structures you can throw at a modern system. If you *can*, use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with `createnode`, so either the code that calls `createnode` is bugged, or the code that indicates that all the nodes are the same is bugged. Since you haven't posted either of those pieces of code it's hard to help. Always remember that you might be wrong about the location of your bug.

Comment: OK, I think @user4581301 has already spotted the problem. But as I said, remember you might be wrong about where your bug is. It's natural to think when you have what seems to be a faulty list that the list hasn't been built correctly, but remember that it could just as easily be that the code that is accessing the list is bugged. That seems to be the case here.

Comment: General linked list recommendation 1: Draw a lot of pictures to help visualize the list and the step-by-step operations performed on the list. Recommendation 2: separate the logic of the list from the logic of what's in the list. This allows you to implement and test both parts separately. Separation of responsibilities makes things smaller and easier to write and verify.

Comment: Another note: Instead of a `createnode` function, consider a smarter `node` constructor.

Comment: thanks @user4581301 that if statement was causing the problem . i will consider all your tips

Comment: @john yes , got it thanks

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes got it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters many member functions has a memory leak as for example in this function

```
    node getnth(int pos)
    {
        node* tmp = new node;
        tmp= head;
        //
```

At first memory was allocated and its address was stored in the pointer tmp and then the pointer is reassigned. As a result the address of the allocated memory is lost and the memory is not deleted.

These statements

```
        node* tmp = new node;
        tmp= head;
```

must be substituted for this one statement

```
        node* tmp = head;
```

Moreover this function

```
    node getnth(int pos)
    {
        node* tmp = new node;
        tmp= head;
        int i =0 ; 

        while(tmp!=NULL){
            if (i=pos) {
            return *tmp;
        }
            i++;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }

    }
```

has undefined behavior in case when pos is higher than there are nodes in the list. In this case the function returns nothing.

In the function `minus` there is used the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator

```
        while(tmp!=NULL){
            if (i=pos) {
                ^^^^^
```

In this function

```
    void delete_first()
    {
        node *temp=new node;
        temp=head;
        head=head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
```

there is no check whether head is equal to NULL and tail is not adjusted if it is point to the first node.

The same problems are also in the function `delete_last` only that instead of the adjacent of the tail node as in the previous function you have to adjust the head node.

This function `delete_position` has the same drawbacks as the previous functions but also it has a bug in the loop

```
for(int i=1;i<pos;i++)
```

A node at position 1 will never be deleted.